# NSCondition: wait for a specified amount of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

This app is a migration from an Android app.

On the Android app I have this code:

```
private Object uploadWorkerLock = new Object();
private static final int UPLOAD_WORKER_SLEEP_TIME = 30000;

[ ... ]

synchronized (ServerManager.this.uploadWorkerLock) {
    try {
        ServerManager.this.uploadWorkerLock.wait(UPLOAD_WORKER_SLEEP_TIME);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

I've a problem with `void java.lang.Object.wait(long millis)`. I can migrate that code this way:

NSCondition* uploadWorkerLock;

```
[ ... ]
[uploadWorkerLock lock];
[uploadWorkerLock wait];
[uploadWorkerLock unlock];
```

Reading Java documentation about [wait(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29), I have read this:
*Causes current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object, or a specified amount of time has elapsed.*

I know I can invoke `[uploadWorkerLock invoke]` but **how can I simulate that the *specified amount of time has elapsed.*?**

By the way, this code is inside of a `NSThread selector`.

Comment: Your problem is that you are to granular when porting your app. The question you should be asking is "how do I upload a file?". Don't try and translate your app line-by-line. While we'r at it. In general avoid `NSThread`. GCD or NSOperation is the way to go.

Comment: Also related to porting. Stay away from using Exceptions for control flow in Objective-C. I know it's how you do it in Java but Objective-C uses NSError and returns nil when there is an error (`nil` is safe to message, there is no null pointer exceptions in Objective-C).

Comment: I think I haven't explained well or I haven't understood: this code is inside a thread on Android, and I have ported to NSThread. Inside the android thread I have the Object.wait, and I don't know how to do it on iOS.

Comment: "and I have ported to NSThread" is your problem. Don't try and port your app line-by-line (or similar granularity). Adopt to the platform you are porting to.

Comment: What are GDC and NSOperation?

Comment: StackOverflow didn't allow me to post LMGTFY links for those two words so I'm just going to say "Google it" (GCD = Grand Central Dispatch)

Comment: All I've have learned reading your comments is that you know how to do it and I don't (which doesn't make much sense because StackOverflow is a tool to help people, not to show us what you know). If I have asked about GDC and NSOperation is to show you that everyone doesn't know what you know.

Comment: I am trying to help you *in the long run*. I'm telling you in broad terms how to approach the problem and future problems related to porting (which you probably will have more if you are porting an app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it simply, with a syntax similar to Java just to don't get confused, that's how to do it:

```
@synchronized(uploadWorkerLock)
{
    usleep(UPLOAD_WORKER_SLEEP_TIME*1000);
}
```

But this isn't the only way, the *@synchronized* directive isn't as fast as spin locks, or a *NSLock*. Another way is [GCD](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.it/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html), which allows you to execute some blocks of code (virtually) at the same time. It is faster than using separate threads, because it will try to optimize things, and it can run two separated blocks of code in the same thread, just simulating multithreading so avoiding context swapping which is expensive.

Also with GCD it isn't hard to do it, but it requires some additional knowledge of blocks and things that can be a bit messy for who just started with Objective-C. Also, GCD isn't a substitute for multithreading, when you have a complex application and every thread doesn't just execute a single block of code, plain multithreading will be more proper.

Comment: Thank you very much for your question. It's very well explained. I have another question: How should I implement that code inside a block? Thanks again.

Comment: It depends on what you need to do, this code is just a "translation" of what you have written in Java.