# NSCondition or @synchronized

Tags: ios, objective-c, locking

I'm developing an iOS 5.0+ app with latest SDK.

I have this code:

```
@interface ServerManager()
{
    NSCondition* statusLock;

[ ... ]

}

@end

@implementation ServerManager

[ ... ]

- (void)setStatus:(ServerStatus)newStatus
{
    [statusLock lock];

    status = newStatus;

    [statusLock unlock];
}
```

If I change `- (void)setStatus:(ServerStatus)newStatus` implementation with this one:

```
- (void)setStatus:(ServerStatus)newStatus
{
    @synchronized(statusLock)
    {
        status = newStatus;
    }
}
```

**Am I doing the same?**

This is my first I work with NSThread and I don't how locks work on iOS.

Comment: Do you really need custom accessor methods? Otherwise you could just define `@property (atomic) ServerStatus;`

Comment: It should be `@property (atomic) ServerStatus status;` in my previous comment (too late to edit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the two pieces of code are *not* equivalent - in order to do the same thing with `NSCondition` as with `@synchronized`, you would have to write significantly more code. According to the overview section of [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html), `setStatus` implementation with `NSCondition` should look something like this:

```
- (void)setStatus:(ServerStatus)newStatus
{
    static BOOL safe_to_set_status = YES;
    [statusLock lock];
    while (!safe_to_set_status) {
        [statusLock wait];
    }
    safe_to_set_status = NO;
    status = newStatus;
    safe_to_set_status = YES;
    [statusLock signal];
    [statusLock unlock];
}
```

If all you need is protection against concurrent modification, using `@synchronized` looks like a much simpler option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm porting an Android app to iOS and I have found on Android this code: `synchronized (statusLock) { status = serverStatus; }`. This is why I'm asking that, because I'm not sure which option is the best to port `synchronized` from Java to Objective-C.

Comment: @VansFannel The `@synchronized` of Objective C is the closest equivalent of Java's `synchronized`. You can use any object for synchronization. If only instance methods are synchronizing on a particular lock, it is very common to use `@synchronized(self)` rather than using a `statusLock` object. In any event, `statusLock` object does not need to be `NSCondition`. In fact, it would be misleading to create `NSCondition` simply to use `@synchronized` on it.

Comment: Thanks again. I don't know how to send you a direct message so I have to ask you here. Could you help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104678/nscondition-wait-for-a-specified-amount-of-time  Thanks.